# Algorithm to find the length of longest suffix between a String and a prefix of the String

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, suffix

**Input:**

There is a long String `S` and we have a array of integers `A` which denotes the prefixes of the String `S` like `A[i]` denotes the prefix `S[0..A[i]]`

**Output:**

Return an array `Output[]` of the same size as `A` where `Output[i]` is the length of the longest matching suffix of `S[0..A[i]]` and `S`

**Sample Input:**

```
S = "ababa"
A[]=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Sample Output:**

`Output[]=[1,0,3,0,5]`

The most naive algorithm which I have is for every `A[i]` just match the number of characters between `S[0..A[i]]` and `S` from the end of both strings. But this algorithm is `O(n^2)` where n is the length of the original String S.

**Question:**
Is there is a better algorithm which pre processes the string S and then can quickly return the longest length suffix for the entire input Array?

Comment: Could you explain what `S[1..A[i]]` is supposed to be? The substring from `1` till `A[i]`?

Comment: sorry updated the Question. it should have been `S[0..A[i]]` which is the substring from `0` till `A[i]` in S

Comment: @Tim - the substring from position `0` to position `A[i]` in `S`.

Comment: Ok, and what does the suffix need to match against?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly the prefix should match the suffix, i.e.  for `A[1]` the prefix would be `ab` and since the string doesn't end with `ab` `Output[1]` is 0. Is that correct?  - With that assumption wouldn't it just suffice to see whether the string is symmetric?

Comment: @Thomas `A[1]` would actually be the substring `a`, so that's where I don't understand the example.

Comment: @Tim we need to find the length of longest suffix between the Strings `S` and `S[0..A[i]]`. For Example `S="ababa"` and lets say `A[2]=2` so we need to find the length of the longest suffix between `"aba" (prefix S[0..2])` and `"ababa"` which would be `3` as `"aba"` is the longest suffix

Comment: @Tim taking the comments into account I understand the prefix being the substring from 0 to `A[i]` i.e. from 0 to 1 (inclusive) in the example. At least the sample output makes sense that way.

Comment: @Tim Thomas is correct, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @pgiitu can you add a more elaborate example to your question probably with a longer input string? As an example: if the input was `abaabaabaabaaba` and the prefix was `aba` would the longest suffix be `abaabaabaabaaba` with length 15 (or would it be length 5 since the suffix is 5 times the prefix) ?

Comment: @Thomas the longest suffix would be `aba`. Length of Suffix can be at max the length of short string between the two.

Comment: Do you need Z-function?  http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107  http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/string/z-function.html

Comment: @MBo No I think Z function won't work for me. It is different from my problem.

Comment: @pgiitu Why do you think Z is not work? I think it is the fastest solution.

Comment: I think `suffix array` or `suffix tree` would work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a [Z-function](http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/string/z-function.html) of the reversed string. The slight difference is that the first element of the Z-function is chosen to be equal to the length of *S*. There is an algorithm to calculate the Z-function of a string in *O(n)*

And the algorithm for this problem is as follows:

- S' := reversed S
- Z := Z-function of S'
- for each *i*, Output[i] := Z[Len(S) - A[i] - 1]

For example:

```
S = "baabaaa"
A[] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
Output[] should be [0,1,2,0,1,2,7]

S' = "aaabaab"
Z = Z-function(S') = [7,2,1,0,2,1,0] (with the first element chosen to be Len(S))
```

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm / datastructure you are looking for is called **Suffix Tree** it has a worst case complexity of `O(n log n)`

> In computer science, a suffix tree (also called PAT tree or, in an
>   earlier form, position tree) is a compressed trie containing all the
>   suffixes of the given text as their keys and positions in the text as
>   their values. Suffix trees allow particularly fast implementations of
>   many important string operations. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree))

[Here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/suffixtrees.pdf) you can find some slides which explain the functionality and implemenation in detail